# How to demand multi objects by for loop

Tags: c#

I wish you a nice day
I have a number of labels inside windows form, for example with these names
label1, labels2, label3, labels4 ... and so on

How to create a for loop to make changes to all or some of them  properties according to a condition that depends on the number inside the label name

My respects

Comment: Put it into a sequence `new [] { label1, labels2, label3, labels4 }.Where(x => condition(x);`, then call `foreach (var x in sequence) { makeChanges(x); }`

Comment: Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's Windows Forms, and assuming the label names all start as "label", you can use the `Form.Controls` index property to get the labels. So you could loop like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var myLabel = this.Controls["label" + i.ToString()] as Label;
    //Do stuff with myLabel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Label.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label?view=net-5.0) property on each label to [get and set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.text?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Label_Text) the text on them.

To iterate through them just place them into a an array or list.

For example we can do

```cs
private Label label1;
private Label label2;
private Label label3;

void DoSomethingWithLabels()
{
    Label[] labels = { label1, label2, label3};
    
    foreach(var item in labels)
    {
        if(item.Text == "SomeText")
        {
             // do something
        }
        else
        {
             item.Text = "Hello World!";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        Label[] teste = { label1, label2, label3, label4 };

        foreach(var label in teste)
        {
            label.Text = "ALTERED";
        }
```